# Why does the about me variable only count to 1 when there are many more?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, active-directory, powershell-ise

The code is deigned to count the number of times users have filled out the 'About Me' section in the user profile service. However, the variable `abtMeNonEmpty` only counts `1` when there are many more? What is the issue?

```
$TestGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=name,DC=name,DC=name,DC=name" -Properties SAMAccountName | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object SAMAccountName

$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext -Site "http://blahblahblah"
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

#loops through all profiles in the profile manager
foreach ($prof in $profiles) {

    $str_abt = $prof["AboutMe"].value
    $str_prov = $prof["Province"].value

    #checks if user is active
    if ($prof.AccountName.IndexOf($TestGroup) -eq -1){
        $numOfActiveSP++

        #checks number of about me filled out
        if($str_abt) {
            $abtMeNonEmpty++ 
        } 

        #checks how many provinces filled out also have about me
        if($str_prov -and $str_abt) {
            $regAboutMeNonEmpty++

            $str_prov = $str_prov.ToUpper()
            $str_prov = $str_prov.Replace(".", "")
            $str_prov = $str_prov.Replace("-", "")
            $str_prov = $str_prov.Replace(" ", "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `$profiles["AboutMe"].count`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey do you know if there is any built in formatting tool in ise?

Comment: @shadow2020 i first need to check that the user is not disabled

Comment: `($profiles["AboutMe"] | where-object {$profiles.AccountName.IndexOf($TestGroup) -eq -1}).count`

Comment: Supposing that `$prof.AccountName` type is a string and  `$TestGroup` type is `Object[]` (or `PSCustomObject[]`) then `$prof.AccountName.IndexOf($TestGroup)` _always_ returns `-1`. I'd guess that `$TestGroup.SAMAccountName.IndexOf( $prof.AccountName)` could work better?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JosefZ

Comment: @sumi - the usual formatting tool is VSCode with the PoSh addon. that enables `Format Document` ... which works rather well. [*grin*]

Comment: concur with @JosefZ, your active check is backwards, you want to look for $prof.AccountName within the collection of active accounts, but you are currently checking if all of the acitve accounts are in $prof.AccountName